# Equivalence of projections in smaller von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, projection, von-neumann-algebras

I came across the following assertion and I can't understand why it's true.

We are given with two finite equivalent projection $e\sim f$ in some von Neumann algebra $A$ (with a unit of course). It's known that the projection $q=e\vee f$ is also finite, so we infer the algebra $qAq$ is a finite algebra (that is, the unit element is a finite projection).

Now suppose that $q-e\sim q-f$ in $qAq$, **show that** $q-e\sim q-f$ also in $A$.

Thanks in advance.

---

Comment: Technically it is true that $q-e\sim q-f$ in $qAq$ so we don't really need to assume that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every element in $qAq$ is also in $A$. In particular, the partial isometry that realizes the equivalence.

Comment: why does the partial isometry that realizes the equivalence in $qAq$ is also partial isometry in $A$?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? A partial isometry will not stop being a partial isometry depending on which algebra it is.

Comment: but if that was true then for any such $e,f$ finite equivalent projections we would have $e-e \sim e-f$ in $eAe$ (just replace $q$ with $e$) and therefor they would have been equivalent also in $A$ (by what you are saying) so $e-f \sim 0$ in $A$ which means $e-f=0$ which is not necessarily true!

Comment: @john_m If $e,f$ are finite and $e-f$ is a projection, then $e=f$, so your concern is a non-issue.

Comment: @john_m:  Your question was whether $q-e\sim q-f$ in $qAq$ implied the equivalence in $A$. Like I said, that's trivially true: you are assuming that $q-e=v^*v$, $q-f=vv^*$ for some $v\in qAq$. If that happens then, as $v\in A$, you also have the equivalence in $A$. As for "replacing $q$ with $e$": in that case $f\leq e$, so if $0\sim e-f$ in $qAq$, then $e-f=0$, and there is no issue.

Comment: Martin & Aweygan - thank you both, i see now that my question was very silly.